# Error on starting the angular 2 app "getaddrinfo enoent"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, angular2-template

I am new in Angular 2.

On starting the Angular 2 application in CLI with ng-serve.  I am getting an issue. Please check the link of error

http://prntscr.com/fazmzc

Please help me to sort out this.

I already restart my system but no luck.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also faced the same error problem when running ng serve in angular 4.
I resolved the issue by change the port no.(default: http://localhost:4200)

instead of "ng serve"

try the below code,

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201

It works and run the project successfully.